Turning off responding to the mouse when computer in sleep mode
Can I turn off responding to the mouse when the computer is in sleep mode (which leads to undesired wake up)? Sometimes I touch the mouse by mistake and the computer wakes up. I'd be fine with him waking up just by tapping the keyboard (or power button).

Yes, in power management, you can set USB devices to be excluded from wake up events.

Start > Run. Type devmgmt.msc and press ENTER.
Find the mouse and view its properties. Under the "Power Management" tab there is "Allow this device to wake the computer."
However, in my experience, this setting does not always work. The BIOS and the operating system (Windows) both have their own rules for allowing devices to wake the system. Your BIOS may have an option that decides whether it lets Windows make the decision or whether it makes the decision itself. If the above answer does not work right away, then explore your BIOS settings.
Even so, I've had a situation where the BIOS setting did not work as expected and as a result it was impossible to stop the mouse from waking the computer.
